# Get JSON data from Arduino with AJAX

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an Arduino with Ethernet Shield. I'm trying to get data from Arduino, using AJAX call.
At the moment I have the following code on Arduino:

> ```
> #include <SPI.h>
> #include <Ethernet.h>
>
> byte mac[] = {
>   0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
> };
> IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);
>
> EthernetServer server(80);
>
> void setup() {
>   Serial.begin(9600);
>   while (!Serial) {
>     ; 
>   }
>
>   Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
>   server.begin();
>   Serial.print("server is at ");
>   Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
> }
>
>
> void loop() {
>   float temperatureIndoor;
>   float temperatureOutdoor;
>   EthernetClient client = server.available();
>   if (client) {
>     Serial.println("new client");
>     boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
>     while (client.connected()) {
>       if (client.available()) {
>         char c = client.read();
>         Serial.write(c);
>         if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
>           client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
>           client.println("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
>           client.println("Server: Arduino");
>           client.println("Connnection: close");
>           client.println();
>
>           temperatureIndoor = 22.77;
>           temperatureOutdoor = 15.55;
>           client.print("{\"0\":{\"TemperaturaInterior\":\"");
>           client.print(temperatureIndoor);
>           client.print("\",\"TemperaturaExterior\":\"");
>           client.print(temperatureOutdoor);
>
>           client.print("\"}}");
>           client.println();
>           break;
>         }
>
>       }
>     }
>     delay(1);
>     client.stop();
>     Serial.println("client disconnected");
>   }
> }
> ```

I'm trying to get values with the following ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.177/',
        type: 'post',
            data: { tag: 'getData'},
            dataType: 'json',
                  async: false,
                  success: function (data) {

$('#TemperaturaInterior').val(data.TemperaturaInterior).show();
$('#TemperaturaExterior').val(data.TemperaturaExterior).show();

                            }
                        });
```

If I access directly from the browser to Arduino (192.168.1.177) I get the correct JSON reply from arduino:
{"0":{"TemperaturaInterior":"22.77","TemperaturaExterior":"15.55"}}

I'm not getting the values.
Any idea?
Thanks

NOTE:

This what I get when ask to arduino to give me the values:

[image]

Comment: What language is that you're programming in there? AJAX is a technology, not a language.  Also, do you really want that "0" in your AJAX response?

Comment: No, the "0" is not necessary. I'm using a php page, with Jquery.

Comment: My reading of that response says you would have `data.0.TemperaturaInterior` and `data.0.TemperaturaExterior`.

Comment: Why are you sending a POST request? A GET would be more appropriate. Also, when you access directly from the browser it's a GET. And you should look at the actual data on the wire (e.g. with a network sniffer, Firebug, the Chrome developer tools, etc...), not just the (failed) rendering on the browser.

Comment: I've edited my post with a prtscr with the response from arduino.

Comment: Look at the last error message: it's quite explicit, then google "cross origin resource sharing" and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Not specific to Arduino.

Comment: Yeah, you have a wicked-specific error message there. When I see a message with that much information I jump for joy! It's telling you exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Stack Overflow question, but I'll help you a bit. The problem has nothing to do with your Arduino per-say. It has more to do with your PHP/Ajax.

Your code is suited for a completely local setup, but pulls from a remote site, which violates some security protocols build into your browser and jQuery. You need to change your code to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.177/',
    type: 'post',
    data: { tag: 'getData'},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#TemperaturaInterior').val(data.TemperaturaInterior).show();
        $('#TemperaturaExterior').val(data.TemperaturaExterior).show();
        }
    });
(may need slight modifications since you didn't include all PHP/html code)
```

For more information, see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/%20%22jQuery%20Documentation), particularly look at data types and what it says about cross-domain json vs jsonp.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) is a relevant SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch man you are getting burned by CORS. This stack overflow box isn't big enough for me to explain how much of a pain CORS is and how much trouble it will cause you. That being said there is a really good recourse that will help explain how to get this working with a couple of http headers http://enable-cors.org/. Good luck